# How to instantiate variable-containing distribution inside tfp.layers.DistributionLambda

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

I'm trying to build a `tf.keras.Sequential` model using `tfp.layers.DistributionLambda`. I'm following the [`DistributionLambda` example](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/layers/DistributionLambda#examples_2), but would want to replace the `tfd.Normal` with a variable-containing `tfd.TransformedDistribution` with `RealNVP` bijector.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp


model = tf.keras.Sequential((
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.shape(x)[-1]),
    tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: (
        tfp.distributions.TransformedDistribution(
            distribution=(
                tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=tf.zeros(t))),
            bijector=tfp.bijectors.RealNVP(
                num_masked=2,
                shift_and_log_scale_fn=tfp.bijectors.real_nvp_default_template(
                    hidden_layers=[32, 32]))))),
))


x = tf.random.uniform((5, 3))
distribution = model(x)
```

However, this fails with the following:

> The layer cannot safely ensure proper Variable reuse across multiple
> calls, and consquently this behavior is disallowed for safety. Lambda
> layers are not well suited to stateful computation; instead, writing a
> subclassed Layer is the recommend way to define layers with
> Variables.

Notice that the `RealNVP` bijector's variables have to be initialized within the bijector, unlike e.g. the `Normal` distribution's variables in [`DistributionLambda` example](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/layers/DistributionLambda#examples_2), in which they are created at the top-level of `Sequential`.

I wonder if there's a way to use `DistributionLambda` with such a setup where the variables have to be created within the distribution? If so, what's the correct way to handle the variables inside the `DistributionLambda` layer? If not, what would be the recommended way of building a model like this?

Comment: I've exactly the same problem. Is there any progress on this issue?